# Print words(that are 7 letters) in a text file in linux

Tags: linux, awk

Code for 7-letter words in my file:

```
cat file.txt | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n"| tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" | awk '{h[$1]++}END{for (i in h){print h[i]" "i}}'| grep -w "\w\{7\}" -w | sort -nr | cat -n | head -n 5
```

This is the output:[this picture shows the top 5 words written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX6F0.png)

This is the file link: https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/996/file.txt

Comment: Does the file `uly.txt` have just one word per line?

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input/output.

Comment: Format your code

Comment: Put textual sample input, output, and code in your question - no links and no images

Comment: I undid the removal of relevant info (which should be provided directly here, not only linked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GNU `AWK` you often can do what other text processing commands do, I will present subsequent steps starting from

```
cat uly.txt | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n"| tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" | awk '{h[$1]++}END{for (i in h){print h[i]" "i}}'| grep -w "\w\{7\}" -w | sort -nr | cat -n | head -n 5
```

firstly GNU `AWK` has `tolower` among [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) so we can use it instead of `tr` for lowercasing as follows

```
cat uly.txt | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n"| awk '{h[tolower($1)]++}END{for (i in h){print h[i]" "i}}'| grep -w "\w\{7\}" -w | sort -nr | cat -n | head -n 5
```

There is also `length` function which return number of characters, so we can use it instead of `grep` as follows

```
cat uly.txt | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n"| awk 'length($1)==7{h[tolower($1)]++}END{for (i in h){print h[i]" "i}}'| sort -nr | cat -n | head -n 5
```

conidition before action means we only do action if condition is met, note that will also lead to less memory usage as information for words of different length is not kept.

GNU `AWK` is able to sort array in various ways, which are described in [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with `gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) as you use value for storing numbers and want descending order (most common to least common) you should use `@val_num_desc`. This allow replacing `sort`

```
cat uly.txt | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n"| awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}length($1)==7{h[tolower($1)]++}END{for (i in h){print h[i]" "i}}'| cat -n | head -n 5
```

Getting subsequent numbers inside `for` loop might be done using one of increment operators, I would use increment-then-return (pluses before variable) rather than return-then-increment (pluses after variable) as you want to have numbering starting at 1 rather than 0. This will be used in place of `cat -n` that is

```
cat uly.txt | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n"| awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}length($1)==7{h[tolower($1)]++}END{for (i in h){print ++j" "h[i]" "i}}'| head -n 5
```

I used `j` variable as it was not used already. Now we have access to number of line it is easy to end processing after outputing 5 words which will replace `head -n 5` that is

```
cat uly.txt | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n"| awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}length($1)==7{h[tolower($1)]++}END{for (i in h){print ++j" "h[i]" "i;if(j>=5){exit}}}'
```

[Exit statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) allows you to end program. This is especially handy if you have huge file, but get answer you need after processing only relative small part of it.

Rather than preprocessing file using `tr` we can inform GNU `AWK` what it should consider row, by providing *row separator* (`RS`) in this case

```
cat uly.txt | awk 'BEGIN{RS="[^[:alnum:]]+";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}length($1)==7{h[tolower($1)]++}END{for (i in h){print ++j" "h[i]" "i;if(j>=5){exit}}}'
```

`[^[:alnum:]]+` meaning is 1 or more (`+`) of anything but (`^`) alphanumeric characters (`[:alnum:]`). Finally GNU `AWK` is not limited for using standard input - you might use argument to deliver file(s) to process so we might use that for replacing `cat` to get

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[^[:alnum:]]+";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}length($1)==7{h[tolower($1)]++}END{for (i in h){print ++j" "h[i]" "i;if(j>=5){exit}}}' uly.txt
```

Note that piping output of `cat` into tool which can itself read file is generally considered to be antipattern and even has own name: *Useless use of cat*

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
tr [:lower:] [:upper:] < uly.txt | awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sub(/[^[:alnum:]]+$/, "", $i)
        if (length($i) >= 7) h[$i]++
    }
}
END {
    for (i in h) {print h[i]" "i}
}' | sort -nr | cat -n | head -n 5
```

Output:

```
     1  3 QUIXOTE
     2  3 PROJECT
     3  3 GUTENBERG
     4  2 LOCATED
     5  2 HISTORY
```

Comment: Your code gives different answer than `egrep -o '[[:alnum:]]{7,}' pg996.txt | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -rn | head -5`, probably because you don't strip punctuation.

Comment: @jhnc thank you for pointing out. I've fixed the code to remove trailing punctuation.